# Linux kernel.panic not working as expected

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-panic, vps

For the last 2 months I'v been investigating a problem related to some unexpected "freezes" of my Ubuntu VPS.

Somehow my VPS stops working entering an uncontrolled state, which can only be resolved by restarting manually the machine.

I thought the problem was related to memory leaks, so I decided to add the following variables to sysctl to the issue:

```
# panic kernel on OOM
vm.panic_on_oom=1
# reboot after 10 sec on panic
kernel.panic=10
```

At the beginning I thought the problem was solved (since I thought that the issue was related to the panic mode), but apparently it turned out it wasn't.

This is a chart of my VPS usage, and as you can see the cpu goes to 100% in few seconds.

[image]

My second attempt was to add Monit to my VPS, with some rules to prevent situations like this one by stopping some service after a certain usage of memory/cpu. But I didn't solve it.

I can't understand where the problem is, how can I reboot the system automatically when my VPS goes in an uncontrolled state?

UPDATE:

This in an example of my Monit config:

```
if cpu usage > 50% for 2 cycles then alert
if cpu usage > 60% for 2 cycles then restart
if memory usage > 70% for 4 cycles then alert
if memory usage > 80% for 4 cycles then restart
```

Comment: Does the memory usage spike when your VM freezes? Are you using a swap partition? Anything interesting in the syslog? Could you please share more details on how you tried to stop services that are consuming too much memory/CPU time?

Comment: Does the memory usage spike when your VM freezes? Sometimes yes.
Are you using a swap partition? No